# Trackpad with Surface Book cannot navigate 3D View

Tags: 3d-view

I can use blender fine with a mouse, however when using just the built in trackpad of my laptop, I cannot navigate the 3d View at all. No panning, no zooming, no rotating. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal because the default controls for navigating around Blender's viewport all rely on clicking on the scroll wheel of a mouse. No laptops that I know of have a similar input that blender will use by default. You will have to set up the input to how you want to control the viewport. There is an option to 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse' in the User preferences in the input tab that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks man that was quick. and that was kinda dumb of me as well, it was just one check box. haha. thanks a alot!

Comment: "No laptops that I know of have a similar input that blender will use by default.": in my experience, zooming, panning and rotating work fine without changing settings on Mac laptops, by using pinch gestures or several finger drag.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm not a Mac user (nor a heavy laptop user) so it's very possible that other laptops have similar controls as well. Have you found pinch and multi finger drag to be a decent replacement?